# About the name of one plant and some recommendations for taking care of it

Tags: plant-health

I was working in a company office as a maid (house cleaner), and there was one plant that the employee was worried about it healthy.

So, as I am familiar with the SE sites, I am trying to put its photo and ask about the ways that employee could take care more about this plant.

Some of the plant photos are shown below:

[image]

So, if possible, I want to know

What is the name of this plant and try to find out about it's healthy condition.

Also, if possible, I would like to know which care could make it's conditions better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is *Pittosporum tobira*, an evergreen, slightly tender shrub which produces scented flowers from late spring to summer. Its lack of health appears to be cultural - first, it looks like it's suffering from drought and second, the container it's planted in is too shallow for it to produce a good root system; a lack of a good root system means it cannot sustain healthy topgrowth. It needs to be in a container at least 8 or 9 inches deep with drainage holes at the base, and should be watered when the surface of the potting soil feels dry to the touch. Image and further information here https://www.gardenersworld.com/plants/pittosporum-tobira/